# How to use vue development mode with Django

Tags: django, vue.js

I don't know how to run development mode with Django. I'm running webpack and when I finish all the Vuejs work I just bundle all to a folder where Django serves It as a static file. I know taht I've to run webpack with mode development but that doens't work, It gives me a cannot found error.
I'd like to run Vuejs in development mode alongside with Django, how can I do that?
I'll share to you my project structure, my package.json and webpack config.

```
const path = require('path');
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './frontend/Vue/main.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'build.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './static/js'),
        publicPath: '/static/js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js)$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: [
                    { loader: 'babel-loader' }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(css|scss)/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'vue-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        // contentBase: ponerle la ruta del index de django
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'templates'),
        watchContentBase: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        noInfo: true
      },
    plugins: [
        new VueLoaderPlugin()
    ]
}
```

package.json

```js
{
  "name": "TuDistribuidora",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --port 9000 --open",
    "build": "webpack --progress"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/EmiBuffet/TuDistribuidora.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/EmiBuffet/TuDistribuidora/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/EmiBuffet/TuDistribuidora#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-router": "^3.4.5",
    "vuex": "^3.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "sass-loader": "^9.0.3",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.3",
    "vue-style-loader": "^4.1.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "webpack": "^4.44.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
    "bulma": "^0.9.1"
  }
}
```

project structure:
[image: architecture]

Comment: more details on the error message you're getting would be useful

Answer (score 0):

Using [django-webpack-loader](https://github.com/owais/django-webpack-loader) in your Django project in combination with  webpack-bundle-tracker in your webpack build will provide the connection needed to alternate between production/dev Vue builds quickly. The bundle information will be recorded by webpack into a `webpack-stats.json` which will then be used by Django to fetch/load the correct bundles for a given view.

I have an [article explaining step-by-step how to set up a project with the above techniques](https://medium.com/js-dojo/vue-django-best-of-both-frontends-701307871478).

Good hacking!

Comment: Django-webpack-loader is now a bit [outdated and is not being well maintained](https://github.com/owais/django-webpack-loader/issues/246).